# Tensorflow Multi GPU Wrapper with variable scope

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I want to build a universal wrapper for a tensorflow model. 
In the main program you can define your model with building blocks like :

```
def model():
   #-- model structure 

def loss():
   return loss_op

 def optimizer():
   return optimizer_op

 def evaluate():
   return accuracy_op
```

Then the user can input all the building blocks to another function (a wrapper), choose a num_gpus, and it will train the model automatically. But it seems impossible for tensorflow since you have to consider variable scope (to share variables between GPUs), and you cannot define a general structure and hope that it works with multi-GPU structure.

**EDIT**
What i have now is something like that:

```
        opt, _ = self.model_optimizer()

        with tf.variable_scope('multi_gpu'):
            for i in range(self.num_gpus):
                with tf.device('/gpu:{}'.format(i)):
                    with tf.name_scope('Tower_%d' % i):
                        output = self.model(cfg, split_X[i])
                        loss = self.model_loss(output, split_Y[i])
                        tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
                        grads = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
                        if i == 0:
                            with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                                tf.add_to_collection('output',output)
                            self.acc_op = self.model_evaluate(output, split_Y[i])
                        tower_grads.append(grads)

        tower_grads = average_gradients(tower_grads)
        train_op = opt.apply_gradients(tower_grads)
        tf.add_to_collection('train_op', train_op)
```

with self.model, self.model_loss, self.model_optimizer, self.model_evaluate is the building blocks ( functions) from user

It did run , but i might make mistake somewhere since the loss stay constant.

How can I make this kind of structure work with variable scope between GPUs?

Comment: I only vaguely understood the question, but typically you would run your model construction (model()) multiple times creating a variable set for each GPU under a different tower scope. If you are into reading frameworks source code you can take a look at https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/tensorpack which seems to have been solving a similar problem

Comment: Tensorpack indeed solves exactly the same problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer ! I took a look at it. Yes tensorpack did indeed solved the problem. But the thing is, it still define a model structure using it own building blocks or in another words everything happens in the environment of tensorpack. What i want is a pure tensorflow model.

Comment: In tensorpack you can define all the models with pure tensorflow code or tf.layers. It doesn't really care what wrapper you use as long as it's still tensorflow.